# PyQt button is clicked before running

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton

This simple applications needs to perform a calculation a soon as the button is clicked.

When running the program I receive the error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

When investigating my code I came to the conclusion that this is probably caused by the fact that the button operation is clicked before the program is running. Therefore is tries to convert an empty string into an int which cannot be done.

The calculation is performed within another class so I dont know why it wants to perform the calculation.

My question is how prevent the program from performing the click action before it is actually running?

```
class main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        begin_row = 1
        end_row = 4
        self.setWindowTitle('Rekenprogramma')

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        #Defining buttonss
        #Debiet / Flor
        self.lbl = QLabel('Debiet',self)
        self.qle = QLineEdit(self)

        #KV
        self.kvlbl = QLabel("KV",self)
        self.kvle = QLineEdit(self)

        #PressureDrops
        self.pdlbl = QLabel("Pressure Drop", self)
        self.pdle = QLineEdit(self)        

        self.btn = QPushButton('Calculate', self)

        """
        Bulky not relevant code
        """

        #Caclulate Button
        grid.addWidget(self.btn, end_row,1)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(calculations.calculate_kv(int(self.qle.text()), int(self.pdle.text())  ))
        self.show()


class calculations():
# sets parameters for the main application
    def calculate_kv(flow, pressuredrop):
        kv = flow / sqrt(pressuredrop)
        return str(round(kv, 2))
```

Comment: what is `grid`?

Comment: Use this: `self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda : calculations.calculate_kv(int(self.qle.text()), int(self.pdle.text())  ))`This will solve the problem temporarily, but you have another serious error, so that you create the widget class if you are not creating an object.

Comment: @eyllanesc grid is a way to layout your program within the Qt framework. It divides space in row and columns. Just like a spreadsheet. For an example you can check [Zetcode's PyQt 5](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. By creating a new function which then calls the calculation. It removes some clutter and provides a solution.

```
         self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        self.show()

    def calculate(self):
        answer = calculations.calculate_kv(int(self.qle.text()), int(self.pdle.text())  )
        self.kvle.setText(answer)

class calculations():
# sets parameters for the main application
    def calculate_kv(flow, pressuredrop):
        kv = flow / sqrt(pressuredrop)
        return str(round(kv, 2))
```

The problem was that by passing arguments to the

```
answer = calculations.calculate_kv(arguments)
```

function, the code executed. So I think the passing of the arguments should not be done within the signaling.